# Comparing the task complexity of installing three different offenses for American style football in three days

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, combinations, data-analysis

I want to identify the inherent difficulty of installing three separate American rules football offenses by their complexity of practice schedules in three days then relate those offenses back to one another. This information was obtained from [@smartfootball](http://smartfootball.com/gameplanning/why-every-team-should-install-its-offense-in-three-days-and-other-political-thoughts-about-successful-offense#sthash.kOLon2X8.RzCoxhBB.dpbs) on twitter.

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        12 & 20 & 19 \\
        15 & 23 & 21 \\
        16 & 26 & 21 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

By adding up the categories covered each day I obtain a matrix where each column is a different offense(air raid, pro-style and spread in that order) and each row is a different day. Each entry is the amount of task expected to be learned on that day for that offense.

I am new to combinatorics and do not know how I might go about solving this problem. This isn't an assignment problem, yet and the only way I can currently think to compare complexity is adding up the total number seeing that air raid offense has only 43 categories where spread has 61 and 69 for pro-style.

My question: **Can someone point me in the proper direction as to how I might construct this problem to be solved in a more constructive combinatorial way?**

I have thought to maybe turn this into an assignment problem somehow where I assign an extra weight depending on player position and complexity of roles during each different category. This is completely do-able and a reasonable way of splitting identifying complexity of installing the offense.

By complexity I specifically mean [task complexity](http://grandon.com/blog/?p=162). I'm trying to gauge the *complicatedness* of learning these three different offensive styles in three days under these set of axioms proposed by @smartfootball.

I am an undergrad in computer science and want to explore combinatorics more. If you could give me any direction as to where I might look as to how to setup this counting problem I would greatly appreciate it. Even if it is just direction to additional reading I would greatly appreciate that.

Comment: what do you mean by complexity here. what exactly is that matrix.

Comment: @shai horowitz 1) By complexity I mean task complexity specifically http://grandon.com/blog/?p=162 2) The rows are each day in descending order and the columns are each different type of offense. The weight of each entry are the number of tasks expected to be learned in that day for that offensive style.(I will edit the original post to include this information)

Comment: Can you rephrase your post to make it clear what mathematical question you're asking? There isn't enough definition/quantification in this post at the moment to identify a mathematical problem.